# Eclipse error directly following @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Tags: java, android, eclipse, generics

I seem to be having some sort of an issue suppressing a warning that I get from deserializing an ArrayList containing type MyObject, from file.  The error message I am getting is from the line

```
objects = (ArrayList<MyObject>) ois.readObject();
```

It reads:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<MyObject>
```

After I apply the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to the specific warning, it says that my objects object cannot be resolved to a type.

```
ArrayList<MyObject> objects;
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("myfile.txt"));
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    objects = (ArrayList<MyObject>) ois.readObject(); //Getting 'objects cannot be resolved to a type'
    fis.close();
}

catch (Exception e) {
    objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
}
```

This is very strange because if I apply @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to the entire method, the error goes away.  Also, it *IS* occurring on multiple machines, not just on one setup.

Does anyone have any insight as to what is going on that makes this error appear when I suppress only the one instance of the error?

Comment: Interesting, same problem here (eclipse 3.7).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@SupressWarnings("unchecked")` can only be applied to the *declariation* of the object, this will work:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<String> objects = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
```

... but may not solve your problem. The reason for this can be found in the JDK source code. The `@Target` annotation on the `@SupressWarnings` annotation defines the permitted locations:

```
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR, LOCAL_VARIABLE})
```

Comment: Oh my, forgot about the declarations...
[link](http://cleveralias.blogs.com/thought_spearmints/2006/01/suppresswarning.html) - some more info

Comment: and on the top of method also.

Comment: @Rudy: yep, see `@Target` and `METHOD`